# Is there any way to set position of cursor in EditText from left to right 2dp

Tags: android, android-edittext, position, text-cursor

is there any way to set position of cursor in EditText from left to right depend on px.

I use this code

```
EditText etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email);
etEmail.setText("Email");
etEmail.setSelection(2);
```

it work but the Email text not remove. so I change `etEmail.setText("Email")` to `etEmail.setHnt("Email")`

like this

```
EditText etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email);
etEmail.setHint("Email");
etEmail.setSelection(2);
```

but it Error.

Is there any way to set position of cursor in EditText?

this is the first load

[image]

this is want I want

[image]

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/fillbox"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
```

Comment: The hint text is not actual editable text, so you cannot select part of the hint because... it is not editable.

Comment: I want to move cursor from left to right 2dp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set `paddingLeft` attribute in XML

```
  <EditText 
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="BBBBB"
    android:hint="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"/>
```

Or set from code

```
EditText edt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt);

        edt.setPadding(2, 0, 0, 0); //int left, int top, int right, int bottom
```

Checked on real device[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want the edittext should be in middle than use this: `edt.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);`, if you edittext should leave some gap at left side or right side than do the following: `edt.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 0);`

add this in your xml file:

`android:hint="Email" android:paddingLeft="20dp"`

[image]

Comment: @kongkea, check once, its working for me put android:paddingLeft="40dp"